# datetimepicker event error event handling

Tags: powershell

Below is my datetimepicker

```
$datePicker_From                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker_From.Location        = "139, 178"
$datePicker_From.Width           = "212"
$datePicker_From.Format          = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$datePicker_From.CustomFormat    = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

i was trying to write code on the **SelectedDateChanged** event, but got below error.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker] does not contain a method named 'SelectedDateChanged'.
```

Please let me know what is the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$datePicker_From.Add_TextChanged({
    # code here
})
```

Comment: @EmptyCoder Ah, then try TextChanged (updated the answer)